# 16.04 LTS: Installed Upstart by mistake, how do I get rid of it?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, upstart

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with the Gnome shell dm.

I recently installed upstart to launch startup scripts (Now I know that it was dumb...), and when I try to uninstall it with `apt remove upstart`, my Gnome session fails to start, until I reinstall upstart.

Since then I get some errors at launch
(*edit*: specifically `/sbin/plymouthd` : `crashed with SIGSEGV in cript_obj_deref_direct()`)

Two questions:

1. Are Systemd and Upstart conflicting? If yes, should I get rid of Upstart?
2. How can I get rid of Upstart without reinstalling my whole system?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try installing systemd and see if it will remove upstart!

Comment: @George, systemd is already installed: `systemd is already the newest version (229-4ubuntu19).`

Comment: Please try this command `sudo apt-get purge upstart`

Comment: it worked, i'me ashamed i didn't try it...
Feel free to add an answer to that I give you the credits...

Comment: Don't be it happens to us all, glad it worked will add an answer ASAP!

Comment: Just dropped an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a comprehensive removal with:

```
sudo apt-get purge upstart
```

That should help with its complete removal